# Solution of a system of equations in a finite field using Mathematica

Tags: math-software, mathematica

We can solve a system of equations over reals using Mathematica as follows.

```
Solve [x^2+y^2+z^2==1 && x+y==1, {x,y,z}]
```

How one can solve a system of equations over a finite field like GF(2) using Mathematica?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Solve[x^2+y^2+z^2==1 && x+y==1, {x,y,z}, Modulus->2]`

Comment: Alternatively, `Solve[{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, x + y == 1}, {x, y, z}, Modulus -> 2]`.

Comment: This is fine, if you work over the prime field. But has Wolfram implemented support for other finite fields? I asked around about that may be 15 years ago (an am still running Mathematica ver 3.0 :-)

Comment: I think so: `Modulus->8` works.

Comment: I don't think it works. Modulus -> 8 means solve the equation in $\mathbb{Z}_8$. $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is not a field since is characteristic is $8$.